# Media recorder getting start falied in API level 27 (8.1.0)

Tags: android, mediarecorder, google-pixel

I am working on records an audio. The following code works correctly until `API level 25`.

But when recording an audio, an exception ***media recorder start failed*** in pixel device `(API level 27)(8.1.0)` version.

Here is my code.

```
 private void startRecording() {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    } else {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    }
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
    recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
    recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if you have the permissions for recording: `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`

And make sure that the app has allowed that requested permission at runtime.